# Can I set default engine for use with @Template annotation?

Tags: view, symfony

I have a project where I use only PHP Templates (instead of twig). Where can I set the default engine for `@Template` so I do not have to do the below all the time?

```
@Template(engine="php")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config.yml I think the following should work:

```
framework:
    templating: { engines: ['php'] }
```

Comment: But the profiller bar uses twig I think, I cant do that then. I also think, that might not solve the problem as looking at the source, `protected $engine = 'twig';` its hardcoded in. I think the right way might be to change that in config/bootstrap/init or something?

Comment: Maybe it's not possible by configuration then: https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/pull/55